# What is the convention for where to place certain types of certs?

Tags: c#, certificate, store, convention

I am trying to understand how to properly programatically install CA, server and client SSL certificates on windows.  I have been unable to discover any over-arching scheme or convention to use when searching for a particular type of certificate.  It appears that Root is used for CAs, Trusted People for Client certs and maybe Server certs but I can only guess from what examples I can find and by what certificates I already see installed on a typical machine.
What algorithms do the various browsers use?
What is the algorithm windows uses when you install a cert that has declared its purpose?
Is there an RFC or something that defines this?

Specifically how might I:
Locate all trusted client SSL certs on a windows machine using c#?
Same for trusted server certs and trusted CA roots and intermediate certs.
Where is the best logical and physical place to put each of these types of certs programatically so all browsers can find them?

Enumeration over all possible locations would seem to be required here.

Comment: Context:  I am creating a C# COM object to interface a windows client app with a backend service securely using two-way SSL.  The certs are obtained after credential processing and a custom client cert is generated by the server for each client machine.  CRLs will be used to remove clients if necessary by the server.  The COM object does all cert management silently.  The cert has to be where a .net webClient object can use it to connect to the server.

Comment: If you are clarifying the question, please include the above comment in your question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.  Go to the RFC (I found it [here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2459.txt)).  I would strongly suggest anyone trying to do any cert work for the first time take a day and gander at this 123 page tome of Geekness.  I avoided it because I hate wading through huge tedious documents - but the fact is, certs are not simple and reading this RTF first will save you from a lot of wrong guesses.  It will give you the background you need to understand OpenSLL, or any other certificate related tool as well.

Comment: Actually, I didn't fully answer my question but this did help a lot.  I am in the process of writing a certificate managing tool for windows that should help me reverse engineer the answer.  Glad to make this public and free if I can find the appropriate place to put it.